# Ifield, Itype equivalent in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have an eclipse plugin project where I use `org.eclipse.jdt.core.IField`, `org.eclipse.jdt.core.IType` etc in this.
Now I am trying to create a similar plugin in IntelliJ. I can't find equivalent classes for these in IntelliJ API. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into IntelliJ's PSI model. It could be easiest for you to find relevant fields using the [IntelliJ IDEA PSI Viewer](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/11/psi-viewer/). You can just give it a java file source and see what objects it gets parsed into.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i will see this link, but can i use those in my code like Ifield or Itype

Comment: @mangalashenoy - I don't think so, but you should try for yourself.